# If I do a solo hunt does the behemoth become any weaker?

Tags: dauntless

If I did a solo hunt or my squad only had 3 people would the behemoth be weakened to 1/4 health or 3/4 for a squad of three? And would any thing else change either?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to these two links: [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/dauntless/comments/burhet/solo_vs_group_hunts/) and also [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/dauntless/comments/8of9l1/does_the_game_scale_down_if_you_play_solo/) forums, it scale up based on how many players are in the group and at which level they are.
So yeah, the behemoth would be weakened playing solo, or with less members, but the exact health rate is a bit harder to say certainly.